# Google Play Music Playlists

Tags: music, music-player, google-play-music

So I'm just wondering if there is a way to "mass select" a heap of songs and then add them to a playlist all at once instead of having to select one song, add it to a playlist etc. for every song.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using [this](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jetappfactory.jetaudio&hl=hr) apk to play music. To multi select songs, just go to all songs, and tap the button on top right upper corner, and you'll get check boxes by each song where you select them and click play.

Comment: Is it able to scan Google play music? Because I have the majority of my songs purchased from the Play Store.

Comment: If it's downloaded on your device then yes, if not then no...